# Accidentally Deleted </script> in Custom HTML Field on Cargo Collective

Tags: html, content-management-system

i accidentally deleted it and saved it, and the i refreshed the site and everything is just a blank white screen. i cant even see my admin page, though i can still login. help!!

I'm trying to find a way to use a proxy tool to intercept the HTTP response and fix the broken script tag, and then fix it in the UI, but i'm not having any success there yet.

Is there a way I can restore the site, or load a previous version of the site?

this is what i could find on Chrome Developer Tools

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a 404 in a JSON request

Answer (score 0):

1. well you can roll back if its in your hosting abilities. Check your hosting
2. is it late to press ctrl + z to the previous results
3. maybe the whole code share could help. because right now I see that you have a JSON error. Where is the line from where it fires